# Open, closed, bounded, unbounded and sequentially compact.

Tags: analysis

Is the set $A$ open, closed or neither, bounded or unbounded, sequentially compact or not sequentially compact.

$A=\{(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2 : 1 < xy < 2\}$.

Can someone please explain why.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Do you know the definitions of open, closed, bounded, unbounded, and sequentially compact?

Comment: Hopefully this helps with the understanding of the definitions:

Is $A$:

**open**?

This means that all points of $A$ are interior points, which means that  for every point in $A$, there exists some epsilon neighborhood that is contained in $A$.

**closed**?

This means that all limit points of $A$ are in $A$. Recall, a limit point of $A$ is a point $x$ that intersects both $A$ and $A^c$, for every epsilon neighborhood of $x$.

**bounded**?

This means that $m\leq a\leq M$ for all $a\in A$, where $m,M\in X$ (assuming $A\subset X$)

Comment: **unbounded**?

This means there doesn't exists $m,M$ such as above.

**sequentially compact**?

This means that all infinite sequences in $A$ have a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

It is an open set because it is the inverse image of an open set by a continuous map. Precisely let us consider $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(x,y)=xy$. It is continuous and $\phi^{-1}((1,2))=A$

It is not closed because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected and $A$ is a proper subset.

It is therefore not compact nor sequentially compact

It is not bounded because $\forall n, (3n,\frac{1}{2n})\in A$ and when $n \rightarrow \infty$ the distance between this point and say $(3/2,1)$ goes to infinity.